# error on string literal jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

So I want to create charts from jsp using fusioncharts. I'd choose fusioncharts then JFree, canvasjs or any other because I'd experiences using it in php language. It should be no problem in jsp because jsp and php are literally same, mapping above html, with only differences is their syntax. However, as I've done the code, it return String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote error on sql statement. Please help me because I am a beginner to jsp and java environment. Thank you.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="com.google.gson.*" %>
<%@page import="readConfig.readConfig" %>

<%
String hostdb = readConfig.getProperties("conUrl");              // MySQl host
String userdb = readConfig.getProperties("dbUser");              // MySQL username
String passdb = readConfig.getProperties("dbPass");                 // MySQL password
String driver = readConfig.getProperties("dbDriver");           // MySQL driver               

DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(hostdb , userdb , passdb);

%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Creating Charts with Data from a Database - fusioncharts.com</title>

    <script src="vendor/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="chart"></div>

    <%@page import="fusioncharts.FusionCharts" %>

    <%
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String sql= "SELECT m.month,IFNULL(x.cnt, 0) AS cnt FROM
(SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%c') as month, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ssl_sales where YEAR(date)=2017 AND status_ssl='new' GROUP BY month) AS x ON m.month = x.month
ORDER BY m.month DESC";

        PreparedStatement pt=con.prepareStatement(sql);    
        ResultSet rs=pt.executeQuery();

        Map<String, String> chartobj = new HashMap<String, String>();

        chartobj.put("caption", "Top 10 most populous countries");
        chartobj.put("showValues", "0");
        chartobj.put("theme", "zune");

        ArrayList arrData = new ArrayList();
        while(rs.next()) {
            Map<String, String> lv = new HashMap<String, String>();
            lv.put("label", rs.getString("Monthly"));
            lv.put("value", rs.getString("New Demand"));
            arrData.add(lv);             
        }

        rs.close();

         Map<String, String> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();  

         dataMap.put("chart", gson.toJson(chartobj));
         dataMap.put("data", gson.toJson(arrData));

        FusionCharts columnChart= new FusionCharts(
                    "column2d",                
                    "chart1",                
                    "500","300",            
                    "chart",                
                    "json",                    
                    gson.toJson(dataMap)     
                );

        %>

        <%=columnChart.render()%>

</body>
```

error on eclipse terminal

```
Mar 27, 2018 2:07:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/registration] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 78 in the jsp file: /dashboard.jsp
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
75: 
76: 
77:             // Form the SQL query that returns the number of sales in 2017
78:             String sql= "SELECT m.month, IFNULL(x.cnt, 0) AS cnt FROM
79:     (SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS m
80:     LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%c') as month, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ssl_sales where YEAR(date)=2017 AND status_ssl='new' GROUP BY month) AS x ON m.month = x.month
81: ORDER BY m.month DESC";


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 78 in the jsp file: /dashboard.jsp
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
75: 
76: 
77:             // Form the SQL query that returns the number of sales in 2017
78:             String sql= "SELECT m.month, IFNULL(x.cnt, 0) AS cnt FROM
79:     (SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS m
80:     LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%c') as month, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ssl_sales where YEAR(date)=2017 AND status_ssl='new' GROUP BY month) AS x ON m.month = x.month
81: ORDER BY m.month DESC";
```

Comment: please post the error

Comment: @useless'MJ i've edited my post to suits you better. help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Java String literals are not allowed  more than one line .

so you can do using '+' like

```
String sql= "SELECT m.month,IFNULL(x.cnt, 0) AS cnt FROM "+
" (SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS m "+
" LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%c') as month, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ssl_sales where YEAR(date)=2017 AND status_ssl='new' GROUP BY month) AS x ON m.month = x.month "+
" ORDER BY m.month DESC";
```

or write it in one line

```
String sql="SELECT m.month,IFNULL(x.cnt, 0) AS cnt FROM (SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS m LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%c') as month, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ssl_sales where YEAR(date)=2017 AND status_ssl='new' GROUP BY month) AS x ON m.month = x.month ORDER BY m.month DESC";
```